# Do high resolution PID chips exist?

Tags: pid-controller

Ideally I am looking for a single chip solution to PID control where ADC/DAC resolution is a minimum of 24 bits. Does anything like this exist or do I have to put it together from separates?

Comment: sounds like an opamp.

Comment: It isn't. I want a pure digital control section

Comment: What sampling rate? And what single chip solution do you have that isn't 24 bits?

Comment: Sampling around 20 per second, and I have no single chip solution at all. If I wanted 12/12 I could use STM32F303 or any number of MCUs. That's why I am asking the question

Comment: Why on earth do you want such a high level of precision?

Comment: @pjc50 Because it would be part of a control loop for a microbalance measuring below 50 nanogram resolution

Comment: Sorry - one gram. I can get better than 50ng by time averaging if I can get a full 24 bits

Comment: You have convinced me you have to put it together from separate parts.

Comment: I think ultimately a one-chip solution would have to be a compromise, DSP signals and microvolt analog signals make poor neighbours. So I'd be looking for separate CODEC and processor. (ADC and DAC in the same package are plausible, but even that may be asking too much)

Comment: Bit of googling suggests http://www.rohm.com/web/global/products/-/product/BU9406KS2 ? High bit depth audio gear is certainly the place to look, although watch out for poor DC performance.

Comment: @MattYoung I am looking at AD7175-2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you insist on a single chip solution, then there are a few microcontrollers with 24-bit sigma-delta ADCs on them. Typically 12 bits is enough for the DAC since it's on the other side of the controller (after all, **1 bit** can be good enough to get 10-12bit PV control accuracy). Note that single-chip discrete '24-bit' ADCs might give you 18-20 bits ENOB (equivalent number of bits) over a reasonable bandwidth. 24 real bits (0.06ppm) is probably a bit of a pipe dream in most circumstances.

For example, the [ADUCM361](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADuCM360_361.pdf).

If you need the best performance, particularly DC bias and gain stability, you're stuck with separate chips. The speed of micro you need will be determined by how fast you have to do the calculations. At a few Hz, even an 8-bit micro may be fast enough (especially using fixed-point math). If you need to do 1kHz or higher, you might be looking at an ARM or even something with a double-precision FPU on board (single precision isn't quite good enough most likely, at least not without some fiddling).

It's quite straightforward to implement a textbook PID algorithm but anti-reset windup, gain scheduling, heat/cool, self-tuning and other fixes and augmentations to the textbook algorithm might get a bit more challenging.